# Why is this true of a submartingale?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Suppose $(X_n, \mathbb F_n)$ is a submartingale. A proof that I am currently reading seems to use that
$$EX_n \geq E X_0$$
Is that true in general? If so, how does it follow from the submartingale property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_n$ is a submartingale, then $\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid \mathbb{F}_{n-1}] \geq X_{n-1}$. Taking the expectation of both sides, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathbb{F}_{n-1}]] &\geq \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}]\\
\mathbb{E}[X_n] &\geq \mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}].
\end{align*}
This holds for all $n$, so stringing these inequalities together gives
$$\mathbb{E}[X_n] \geq\mathbb{E}[X_{n-1}] \geq \cdots \geq \mathbb{E}[X_1] \geq \mathbb{E}[X_0].$$

Comment: Why does $\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid X_{n-1}] \geq X_{n-1}$ hold? The defining property says that $\mathbb{E}[X_n\mid \mathbb F_{n-1}] \geq X_{n-1}$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It does not change the result though.

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathbb{F}_{n-1}]] = \mathbb{E}[X_n]$ ?

Comment: The definition of $\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathbb{F}_{n-1}]$ says that $\int_A\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]  \ dP= \int_A X_n \ dP$ for any $A \in \mathbb{F}_{n-1}$. In particular the entire sample space $\Omega$ is in $\mathbb{F}_{n-1}$, so $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}]] = \int_\Omega \mathbb{E}[X_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}] \ dP = \int_\Omega X_n \ dP = \mathbb{E}[X_n]$.